# Spin Representations and Galois correspondence?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I have a vague question regarding the Spin representations.

Is there a "quick" way of seeing that $Spin(2n)$ has exactly two irreducible representations which do not factor through $SO(2n)$, and one for the odd case?

Of course, there is the classification of representations and one can write out all the representations for both the groups and see that this is indeed the case. But I was wondering if without doing all that just by using the fact that $Spin(2n)$ double covers $SO(2n)$ can one see this?

Even more vaguely, is there some kind of a Galois correspondence between the irreducible representations of compact Lie groups and $Spin(2n+1)$ is not a *Galois cover* of $SO(2n+1)$?

Thank you.

Comment: Of course, one can write down an explicit spinor representation and show that there are elements in $SO(m)$ whose two preimages in $Spin(m)$ act distinctly on the representation.

Comment: Yes, but this does not answer the question as to why there can be only two and not more.

Comment: There are many irreducible representations of $Spin(m)$ that do not factor through $SO(m)$, no? Simply take the Cartan product of any representation that does with a fundamental spin representation. I suppose you mean that there are exactly two fundamental representations of $Spin(2n)$ that do not factor through $SO(2n)$, but simply talking about fundamental weights means you have the notion of weights available, and this is already something like "writing out all the representations".

Comment: In other words, I don't know how to answer what I assume your question means, because I don't know one can "see" whether a representation is fundamental without doing something tantamount to "writing out all the representations".

Comment: May be I'm overthinking and does amount to finding the fundamental weights. I am really looking for some kind of Galois correspondence, but may be there is none. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope they were useful.